# Maven: Build class path order

Tags: java, maven, build

I have 2 project A and B.
Each has an interface "I" with its implementation.
In Project A, I want to use the implementation "I" of the project B, and it is not enough to add the dependency of project B to get there.
I ask the necessary configuration in pom.xml of the project A.

Answer (score 0):

Research about writing a '***reactor build***' file that would reference both projects and thus build them both; this build would first see which project **depends** on the other and thus build the **dependency** first.